# Counting using dictionary and removing irrelevant values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am working on school work and I have been struggling hard to think of a solution.

We are asked to count letters in a random word using dictionary (let's say `"ADASDA$dadqEQE@!$aQ"`). The counting should be case-agnostic and non-alphabetics cannot be used. I have done some online searching and seems that everyone basically uses `isalpha()` or regex but they are both not allowed in my case.

I thought about adding a specific list first (all 26 ASCII letters) so that non-alphabetical characters won't be counted. After that, we can remove the entries with 0s. However, I seem to struggle executing the last step to remove the 0s. The last part is probably wrong, but I am not sure what is the right way of saying removing all entries with 0 value.

```
def count_letters(string):
    lettercount = {"A" : 0,
                   "B" : 0,
                   "C" : 0,
                   "D" : 0,
                   "E" : 0,
                   "F" : 0,
                   "G" : 0,
                   "H" : 0,
                   "I" : 0,
                   "J" : 0,
                   "K" : 0,
                   "L" : 0,
                   "M" : 0,
                   "N" : 0,
                   "O" : 0,
                   "P" : 0,
                   "Q" : 0,
                   "R" : 0,
                   "S" : 0,
                   "T" : 0,
                   "U" : 0,
                   "V" : 0,
                   "W" : 0,
                   "X" : 0,
                   "Y" : 0,
                   "Z" : 0}
    for i in string.upper(): 
        if i in lettercount:
            lettercount[i] += 1
    for value in lettercount:
        if value == 0:
            lettercount.remove(value)
    return lettercount
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `collections` then I'd suggest `collections.Counter`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> s = "ADASDA$dadqEQE@!$aQ"
>>> c = Counter(i.upper() for i in s if i in ascii_letters)
>>> c
Counter({'A': 5, 'D': 4, 'Q': 3, 'E': 2, 'S': 1})
```

If doing this by hand, instead of per-defining your dictionary simply add elements as they are encountered

```
from string import ascii_letters
lettercount = {}
for letter in s:
    if letter not in ascii_letters:
        continue
    if letter.upper() in lettercount:
        lettercount[letter.upper()] += 1
    else:
        lettercount[letter.upper()] = 1

>>> lettercount
{'A': 5, 'D': 4, 'S': 1, 'Q': 3, 'E': 2}
```

Comment: Hi Cory, thanks a lot. We aren't allowed to use collections either. For the second one, I don't understand how it works though (anyway, we aren't allowed to use ascii_letters either). Does it screen out all non alphabets?

Comment: @user16508102 `ascii_letters` is literally just the string `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'` so you can define your own `ascii_letters` and just set it equal to that string

Comment: @user16508102: Also, `collections.Counter` is just a dictionary subclass and would not be very difficult to replace with a regular one — just make sure not to add any keys to it that aren't ASCII letter characters.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are not correctly iterating values of dictionary. Writing `for i in lettercount` gives keys of dictionary. For example,

```
>>> lettercount = {'A':2, 'B':1}
>>> for i in lettercount:
        print(i)
    
A
B
```

There are a few ways to iterate values, one of the is as follows:

```
>>> for key, value in lettercount.items():
    print(key, value)

    
A 2
B 1
```

Once you check values, you should remove keys (not values) dictionary, but you shouldn't remove element from a data structure you are iterating. Instead, you can add 0 letters to new list, then iterate through that list to remove elements from dictionary:

```
for i in string.upper(): 
    if i in lettercount:
        lettercount[i] += 1
zero_letters = []
for letter, count in lettercount.items():
    if count == 0:
        zero_letters.append(letter)
for letter in zero_letters:
    lettercount.remove(letter)
return lettercount
```

But there is a better way to tackle this problem. You don't need to create a dictionary with 0 values.

```
def count_letters(string):
    uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    letters_dict = {}
    for i in string:
        upper_letter = i.upper()
        if upper_letter not in uppercase: continue
        letters_dict[upper_letter] = letters_dict.get(upper_letter, 0) + 1
    return letters_dict
```

Comment: Hi Tuqay, thanks a lot! This works perfectly but I have to add the lower case as well (i.e. "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") even though we have used i.upper function. A bit weird (or maybe I did something wrong on my end) but thank you so much!

Comment: @user16508102, i made a small mistake, fixing that now

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_letters(string):
    lettercount = {"A" : 0,
                   "B" : 0,
                   "C" : 0,
                   "D" : 0,
                   "E" : 0,
                   "F" : 0,
                   "G" : 0,
                   "H" : 0,
                   "I" : 0,
                   "J" : 0,
                   "K" : 0,
                   "L" : 0,
                   "M" : 0,
                   "N" : 0,
                   "O" : 0,
                   "P" : 0,
                   "Q" : 0,
                   "R" : 0,
                   "S" : 0,
                   "T" : 0,
                   "U" : 0,
                   "V" : 0,
                   "W" : 0,
                   "X" : 0,
                   "Y" : 0,
                   "Z" : 0}
    for i in string.upper():
        if i in lettercount:
            lettercount[i] += 1
    for value in range(65,91):
        if lettercount[chr(value)] == 0:
            lettercount.pop(chr(value))
    return lettercount
```

try this.